# Do questions about modeling charges in programming fit here?

Tags: discussion

At electronics.SE we received this question: [Representing charges in computer programming](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23761/representing-charges-in-computer-programming)

The gist of the question comes from this paragraph:

> How can electric charges be represented in terms of programming? Do
>   you have to simulate each and every ion or are there overall
>   principles so you can calculate with "whole" charges? I could imagine
>   Circuit simulations already implement some calculations with
>   electrodynamics.

Does this community think it might fit in here?

Comment: Sounds like a modeling problem. I don't see why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the questioner was asking something related to a simulation, the actual question seemed to be more about physics than simulation per se.

It seems to me that this particular question would fit better in physics than scicomp, but I don't think it's off-topic here.

Comment: Physics actually recommend to check here... see http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/990/do-questions-about-modeling-charges-in-programming-fit-here/991#991

Comment: Ah. Nevermind then.

Comment: I guess if the questioner was looking for something like the answer you gave about charge density, then yeah, it would be a decent fit on Physics. When I read the question I thought it was looking for more computational detail.

Answer (score 2):

This is absolutely relevant to computational chemistry and computational physics!  Bring it over here!